# How to check date lies in the month from JAN to JUNE and JULY to DECEMBER

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a date. I want to check whether the date lies between JAN to JUNE or JULY to DECEMBER. Like suppose if user enter input date 28-NOV-12 then how can i check that this date lies between JULY to DECEMBER ? and if user input date 28-FEB-12 then this date lies between JAN to JUNE? Basically i want to check dates on half yearly basis ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [`to_char` function](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php), e.g. this way:

```
select
    case
        when to_char(date_column, 'mm') <= 6 then '1st' 
        when to_char(date_column, 'mm') >= 7 then '2nd'
    end as half_of_the_year
from your_table
```

`to_char(date_column, 'mm')` returns month (01..12, 01 - January) part of the date.

```
select
    case
        when to_char(sysdate, 'mm') <= 6 then '1st' 
        when to_char(sysdate, 'mm') >= 7 then '2nd'
    end as half_of_the_year
from dual
```

today returns:

```
HALF_OF_THE_YEAR
2nd
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :). I want to ask can i also use this `extract(month from to_char(date_column)) <= 6 then '1st'` ?

Comment: Your answer is ok, i am just asking to do it in another way, using extract ;) otherwise no problem , its ok :)

Comment: @Basit sorry, I deleted my previous comment I didn't noticed (just copied) that you were asking about `extract` :-/. In this case it wasn't right :-/.

Comment: @Basit ... and yes you can use use [`extract`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/extract.php), e.g. `extract(month from date_column)` instead of `to_char(sysdate, 'mm')` :-).

Answer (score 1):

```
select sign(2.5-to_char(<date>, 'q')) from dual;
```

returns `1` for dates between January 1st and June 30th and `-1` otherwise.

**Explanation**:

`to_char(date, 'q')` returns the *Quarter of year (1, 2, 3, 4; January - March = 1)* of *date* ([see format models](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#CDEHIFJA)). For November 28th, that would be 4.

`2.5-quarter` returns a negative number for quarter 3 and 4, and a positive number for quarter 1 and 2, respectively. The `sign` reduces the negative and positive numbers to a simpler `-1` and `1`.

**Testcase**:

```
with da as (
  select date '2012-01-01' te from dual union all
  select date '2012-02-02' te from dual union all
  select date '2012-03-03' te from dual union all
  select date '2012-04-04' te from dual union all
  select date '2012-05-05' te from dual union all
  select date '2012-06-06' te from dual union all
  select date '2012-07-07' te from dual union all
  select date '2012-08-08' te from dual union all
  select date '2012-09-09' te from dual union all
  select date '2012-10-10' te from dual union all
  select date '2012-11-11' te from dual union all
  select date '2012-12-12' te from dual
)
select 
  da.te,
  decode (sign(2.5-to_char(da.te, 'q')),
           1, 'Jan-Jun',
          -1, 'Jul-Dec')
from da;
```

Comment: what is `q`? 2.5 means you express half year as decimal. How this expression evaluates? can you explain it ? thanks

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This logic is very cool :). But another thing why did you use decode...`decode (sign..)` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table "28-NOV-2012" WHERE date_column  between TO_DATE('01-JAN-2012') AND TO_DATE('01-JUN-2012');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,date_column should be date datatype other wise change to TO_DATE(date_column)

```
select
case
    when date_column BETWEEN  TO_DATE('01-JAN-12') AND TO_DATE('03-JUN-12')then '1st Half' 
    ELSE '2nd Half'
end as DatePosition
from table_name
```